# OPA authorization policies with scopes and roles

Tags: authorization, opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I'm using Open Policy Agent as an authorization component together with OIDC enabled apps.

I have input from the apps in the format:

```
{
    "token": {
        "scopes": [
            "read:books",
            "write:books"
        ]
    },
    "principal": {
        "roles": [
            "user",
            "moderator"
        ]
    },
    "context": {
        "action": "read",
        "resource": "books"
    }
}
```

Then I have data with access mapping in the format:

```
{
    "user": [
        "read:books"
    ],
    "moderator": [
        "read:books",
        "write:books"
    ],
    "administrator": [
        "read:books",
        "write:books",
        "read:store",
        "write:store"
    ]
}
```

And the policy currently looks like this:

```
package whatever.authz

context_scope := concat(":", [input.context.action, input.context.resource])

default allow = false

allow {
    token_has_context_scope
    principal_has_resource_access
}

token_has_context_scope {
    context_scope == input.token.scopes[_]
}

principal_has_resource_access {
    principal_role := input.principal.roles[_]
    context_scope == data[principal_role][_]
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
2 errors occurred:
policy.rego:16: rego_recursion_error: rule principal_has_resource_access is recursive: principal_has_resource_access -> principal_has_resource_access
policy.rego:7: rego_recursion_error: rule allow is recursive: allow -> principal_has_resource_access -> allow
```

It is the recursive lookup in the `principal_has_resource_access` function that is causing the error.

I need to check if one of the roles of the principal is allowed to access the resource as specified by the context. Since roles is an array i need to find the union of all access scopes in the data and see if one of them matches the context scope. What am I doing wrong in the policy?

The snippet can be found in the Rego Playground https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/KhovLRgMup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPA stores *all* data under the `data` path, including policy and rules. There's no way for the compiler to know that the input you're providing isn't referencing the policy itself (i.e. `data["whatever"]`) which would be recursive. The easiest way to work around this is to simply use a top level attribute for your data which differs from your policy (i.e package name), like this:

```json
{
    "attributes": {
        "user": [
            "read:books"
        ],
        "moderator": [
            "read:books",
            "write:books"
        ],
        "administrator": [
            "read:books",
            "write:books",
            "read:store",
            "write:store"
        ]
    }
}
```

And update your policy to reference this:

```
context_scope == data["attributes"][principal_role][_]
```

Since `data.attributes` != `data.whatever.authz` there is no risk of recursion, and the compiler won't complain. You might want a better name than "attributes", but I'll leave that to you :)